# How to make a new array from an array of arrays selecting only the elements with desired index

Tags: javascript, arrays

In javascript, I have a variable like:

```
foo = [[5,3,2],[2,7,4],[4,6,3],[2,6,4]]
```

I would like to make a function that I could provide with the array and index, and it would return an array with only the value of that index in each of the elements of the original array.

Example:

```
bar = funtion (foo, 1);

//expected output: bar = [3,7,6,6]
```

What would be a good/smart way to do this?

Comment: Is very easy, have you tried it?

Comment: `for.map(x => x[index])`

Comment: Also, by using index as `2` the result would be `[2,4,3,4]` and not `[3,7,6,6]`.

Comment: Correct DontVoteMeDown, I have edited it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in your example your forgot that arrays are zero-based. So for index `2` answer shall be `[2, 4, 3, 4]`

The function looks like following:

```js
const foo = [[5,3,2],[2,7,4],[4,6,3],[2,6,4]];

function bar(arr, index) {
    return arr.map( subarray => subarray[index] );
}

console.log( bar( foo, 2 ) );
```

Shorter variant:

```js
const foo = [[5,3,2],[2,7,4],[4,6,3],[2,6,4]];
const bar = (arr, index) => arr.map( subarray => subarray[index] );

console.log( bar ( foo, 2 ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
function filterIndexes(2dArr, index) {
    return 2dArr.map(function(subArr) {
         return subArr[index];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
const foo = [
  [5, 3, 2],
  [2, 7, 4],
  [4, 6, 3],
  [2, 6, 4]
]

const bar = function(arr, ndx) {
  return arr.map(e => e[ndx]);
}

const result = bar(foo, 2)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess to way is to iterate the array and create a new one:

```js
foo = [[5,3,2],[2,7,4],[4,6,3],[2,6,4]]
function bar(arr, idx) {
   var selectedArr = [];
   arr.forEach(function(subArr) {
     selectedArr.push(subArr[idx]);
   });
   return selectedArr;
}


document.getElementById("result").innerText = bar(foo,2);
```

```html
<span id="result"></span>
```